# How to change a div border color when clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, use-state

Working on a react/typescript project, I have a div and want to replace the border color and width of a div when it's clicked:

```
   <div
          className="showroom-card "
          onClick={() => setSelection({ showroom: 'Westchester' })}
        >
```

[image]

I know it should be simple but I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: What you should do is pass an `isSelected` prop to div and if it is true change the clasasName to `showroom-card-selected`.

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you can make but please describe more

```
div.style.border="1px solid #000";
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure html/js it would be look like that:

```css
.showroom-card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.selected {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
  <div
    id="card1"
    class="showroom-card"
    onClick="(function(divId) {
      targetDiv = document.querySelector(`#${divId}`)
      targetDiv.classList.toggle('selected') 
    })('card1');return false;"
  ></div>
```

But in react you must use state of component to manipulate div's style. For example, you would use `divToggled` variable in state of your component to render border and manipulate its color. The handler function, named `handleDivClick` change state and component will be rerendered:

```js
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  handleDivClick = () => {
    this.setState(divToggled: !this.state.divToggled)
  }

  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        onClick={this.handleDivClick}
        className={`showroom-card ${this.state.divToggled ? 'selected' : ''}`}
      />
    )
  }
}
```